# Netbeans Files are not refreshed when I change branches

Tags: git, netbeans

As the title says, netbeans files are not refreshed when I change branches. Is there any configuration that I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing it from within Netbeans (via Team > Git > Branch > Switch To Branch) or from elsewhere, like via commandline?

If you are doing it via command line, Netbeans is not aware of the changes until you manually refresh, whereas if you use the context menu in Netbeans it is aware of the change.

Comment: i'm changing via command line. how can I make netbeans aware of the changes? On the Team>Git, there is no branch option. Is there any configuration I should make? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Netbeansh work from projects files, this means you should have something like : ~/Documents/NSProject/myproject folder.
This project folder should have a git repository (.git folder inside ) this is your git LOCAL repository.

Any remote files or folder project has to be treated as a remote repository and only be aware of your local changes when you push your changes to this remote

This already say. If you checkout to another branch in your remote command line, does not update the rest of the files changed .You update only the files SAVED into the LOCAL NETBEANS PROJECT folder and then update the files open and put then into remote folder.